# Crash connection to FTP using CFNetwork

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ftp, cfnetwork

I want to download a file from my FTP using CFNetwork.

The following code crashes allmost everytime i run my iOS Application (iOS 6.0 SDK).
The debugger just says "(lldb)"

http://pastebin.com/5XQD9ih1

I figured out that the App just crashed if i set the Delegate for the inputStream or the outputStream. So it have something to do with the delegate. But without any error message i dont know how to start searching the issue ? any ideas ?

Comment: Have you linked the CFNetwork framework to your project?

Comment: The delegate methode stream:handleEvent: is implemented, but ATM empty.

Comment: If it helps here is the stack in Thread 1 where the crash appears: http://pastebin.com/b56CRbcs

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint? What line is it complaining about? Also, are you using ARC?

Comment: Exeption BP don't make any difference. ARC is enabled. the Apps stops in the line i marked in the second paste. but only if i set the delegate.

Comment: hmm, strange what if you use the gdb debugger? does it complain?

Comment: GDB says: "GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1864.
Catchpoint 2 (throw)Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
[unknown](gdb)"

Comment: So nothing new. Just [unknown] -.- what could it be ?

Comment: Well you mention it was in your delegate methods, what is happening in there?

Comment: its not in the delegate methode. the delegate wasnt called. i meant that the error just appear if i set the delegate from the NSinputStream/NSOutputStream to self. if i dont set the delegate the app dont crash.

Comment: To me, that would appear as something happening in the delegate is causing the error. As when you don't set the delegate, the delegate method is not being called.

Comment: And how can i find the issue to solve the problem ? because between initiate and open the stream and calling the delegate methode is nothing else, or i am right ?